# Is there a sql (redshift) function that will return values that does not contain letters

Tags: sql, wildcard

```
Select memberid not like ‘[A-Z]%’
```

Still returns values that end with a letter
And

```
Select memberid not like ‘%[A-Z]%’
```

I get no results

Answer (score 1):

Select memberid not like '[A-Z]%' will get rid of items that start with a letter.

select memberid not lik '%[A-Z]%' will get rid of everything with a letter.

select memberid not like '%[A-Z]' is probably what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Redshift LIKE doesn't use square brackets for special meaning.  I expect you want to use SIMILAR TO instead.  See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions.html